# In android studio, how can I move ball to point I click?

Tags: android, game-maker, android-studio

I try to create a game like billiards. I want to move the ball the point I clicked.

Comment: https://youtu.be/53zkBvL4ZB4

Comment: Is this question about Game Maker or Android Studio???

Answer (score 1):

On the ball object, create a global left button event and create a script with the following:

`move_towards_point(mouse_x,mouse_y,5);`

The ball will go at a speed of 5 toward the point where you clicked with the mouse.

You can change the speed as you prefer, but to make the ball stop you will have to add the same physical component (friction).